# CSS is not showing

Tags: python, html, django

I am learning Django and while I was trying to load static CSS files, it did not show any output. When I run server I only get HTML as my output.
Here is my code
**settings.py code**

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
                    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
                    'bloodnepal/bloodnepal/static',
                    ]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bloodnepal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css_files/style.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "css_files/link.css" %}'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira Sans Extra Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nanum Myeongjo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
</html>
```

**url.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views                     #imported the views.py files here for our pipeline
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/',views.home,name="Homepage"),
    path('donate/',views.donate,name="Donatepage"),
    path('organization/',views.organization,name="Organizationpage"),
    path('getinvolved/',views.getinvolved,name="Getinvolvedpage"),
    path('about/',views.about,name="AboutUspage"),
] 
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: Does your web server log show that the css files are being requested?  And if so, do the requests use the correct url?

Comment: Use chrome and press F12 on your loaded page to open the dev tools, does the console throws an error saying that the files are missing?

Comment: @RonaldPetit Yes,the console is showing **Not Found** for the image that I am trying to load and it is saying **net::ERR_ABORTED 404(Not Found)** for the CSS files.

Comment: @JohnGordon I didn't understand what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store your CSS inside your project folder under "static" directory then the following code for settings.py should work:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

....

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder'
]
```